# How to use a custom hook within reduce callback function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-query

I have an array of 'property' objects. I'd like to reduce them to a single 'total monthly revenue' value. However, this requires a db call for each individual object.

The db call happens within a custom hook, using react-query. This doesn't work inside a useEffect hook because of the custom hook. I'm not sure how to structure this operation.

The gist:

```
    const [properties, isLoading, isError, error] = useGetOwnedProperties()
    const [totalRev, setTotalRev] = useState(0)

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!properties) {
            setTotalRev(0)
        } else {
            setTotalRev(properties.reduce((acc, cur) => {
                const [revenue, revLoading] = useMonthlyRevenue(cur) // Not sure where this should happen
                return revenue + acc
            }))
        }
    }, [properties, isLoading])
```

Comment: Hooks must be called in the same order on every render, so `useMonthlyRevenue` must be called outside the `useEffect` callback.

Comment: They also can't be called in a loop like you're doing with `reduce`, maybe change the hook to accept `properties` as an argument directly